# .NET library to interact with a webpage programmatically

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ui-automation

I need to parse some information from a website.

I know there are some testing tools that do that, but I need it to be done in real time, from ASP.NET webpage code. So I guess, I need a .NET library.

Previously I was just able to generate a specific URL and parse the HTML but now I have to get information from a page that is generated by AJAX calls after form clicks. So I have to generate those clicks, right?

BTW I only have (limited) experience with server side ASP.NET. Maybe the optimal solution is quite different to what I suspect?

Comment: Use fiddler to see the POST and GET and the Content then you can use a bare WebClient to mimick the same.

Comment: @rene if you expanded that idea I would probably mark it as answer

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at [`WatiN`](http://watin.org/).

From the homepage:

> - Automate all major HTML elements with ease
> - Find elements by multiple attributes
> - Native support for Page and Control model.
> - Supports AJAX website testing
> - Supports creating screenshots of webpages
> - Supports frames (cross domain) and iframes
> - Handles popup dialogs like alert, confirm, login etc..
> - Supports HTML dialogs (modal and modeless)
> - Easy to integrate with your favorit (unit) test tool
> - Works with Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9 and FireFox 2 and 3
> - Can be used with any .Net Language
> - Licensed under the Apache License 2.0
> - Downloaded more than 120.000 times.
> - And since its open source you can add and contribute new features yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu). It wraps WatiN and Selenium giving you helper methods that make this kind of work a lot easier.